# Java -The method sleep(int) is undefined for the type Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm getting an error: The method sleep(int) is undefined for the type Thread. I thought the sleep method is in the Thread class in Java.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Thread implements Runnable {

    String name;
    int time;
    Random r = new Random();

    public Thread(String s){
        name = s;
        time = r.nextInt(999);
    }

    public void run() {
        try{
            System.out.printf("%s is sleeping for %d\n", name, time);
            Thread.sleep(time);
            System.out.printf("%s is done", name);
        } catch(Exception e ) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: actually, why doens't people read the errors generated ??

Comment: I do read the error. That is why I copy and paste the error message I am getting.

Comment: What you could have done is search for the method in java doc and figure it out on your own. anyway, it's good you found an answer :)

Answer (score 18):

You implemented your own class called `Thread` and try to call `sleep` on it, which fails, cause `sleep` is undefined in your class. Your class basically shadows java's `Thread` class.

Call your class differently (ie. `MyThread` or even better `MyRunnable`, as noted by owlstead) or call `java.lang.Thread.sleep()` directly.

Comment: +1: A good example of why you shouldn't give your classes the name of standard classes.

Comment: MyThread would be a strange name for something that implements Runnable without *being* a thread. Instead of Runnable, you could extend Thread and name it MyThread (see the JavaDoc for Thread on how). Note that to start it up, don't call run() but call start(), otherwise no new thread will be generated. Personally, I would not go that way and stick with Runnable though.

Comment: @owlstead maybe it wouldn't be correct semantically but at least it would compile. `MyThread` was just an example.

Comment: @Peter, I recall several years ago working mostly in C#, someone made an important class String in some package. When used w/ w/ capital S (`String`) the code won't work since it referenced the class in the same package and didn't mean `System.String` but XXX.String and using it w/ regular s (`string`) worked. Of course, coming from java I used capital letters for classes. Heck, that was hell of a nonsense losing me almost an hour in debug to resolve simple casting issue.

Answer (score 6):

It's not in *your* `Thread` class.

Since you named your class `Thread`, that's where Java will look for `Thread.sleep`.  If you want the function that's built into Java, try `java.lang.Thread.sleep(time);`.

Answer (score 2):

Your class name "Thread" conflicts with the Thread class in Java standard library. Change the name of your class and it will resolve everything.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting this is that you've implemented your own Thread class.  In your class there is no sleep method.

First prize would be to avoid using class names that are part of the standard Java libraries.

If you insists to keep the names, use java.lang.Thread.sleep(...) to specify that you want the Thread class that Java provides.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I'm going to do avoid using Java standard names for class names

Answer (score 1):

Fully-qualify `Thread` since you're trying to use `java.lang.Thread`, not your own.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your class is named `Thread`, which doesn't have a `sleep()` method. The sleep method is in `java.lana.Thread`, which is being hidden by your class.

Answer (score 0):

Answers to this question have already been posted yet one another analogy. It may not be the direct answer but may help you remove your confusion why should **avoid reusing the names of platform classes, and never reuse class names from java.lang**, because these names are automatically imported everywhere.
Programmers are used to seeing these names in their unqualified form and
naturally assume that these names refer to the familiar classes from `java.lang`. If
you reuse one of these names, the unqualified name will refer to the new definition
any time it is used inside its own package.

---

One name can be used to refer to multiple classes in different packages. The following simple code snippet explores what happens when you reuse a platform class name. What do you
think it does? Look at it. It reuses the `String` class from the `java.lang` package. Give it a try.

```
package test;

final class String
{
    private final java.lang.String s;

    public String(java.lang.String s)
    {
        this.s = s;
    }

    @Override
    public java.lang.String toString()
    {
        return s;
    }
}

final public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s = new String("Hello world");
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

This program looks simple enough, if a bit repulsive. The class `String` in the
unnamed package is simply a wrapper for a `java.lang.String` instance. It seems
the program should print **Hello world**. If you tried to run the program, though,
you found that you could not. The VM emits an error message something like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main
```

If you're using the NetBeans IDE, the program would simply be prevented from running. You would receive the message **No main classes found**.

---

The VM can’t find the `main` method because it isn’t there. Although
`Main` has a method named `main`, it has the wrong signature. A main method
must accept a single argument that is an array of strings. What the
VM is struggling to tell us is that `Main.main` accepts an array of ***our String***
class, which has nothing whatsoever to do with `java.lang.String`.

---

**Conclusion :**  As mentioned above, always avoid reusing platform class names from the `java.lang` package.