# Random doesn't work

Tags: java, random

We wrote this piece of code in class and it worked perfectly, but when I copied it to my computer at home I got a red line under the 'nextInt' and a message that said:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method nextInt(int) is undefined for the type Random
```

---

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int x, sum=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        sum=0;
        x=rnd.nextInt(29)+2;
        for (int j = x-2; j < 0; j=j-2)
        {
            sum+=j;
        }
        System.out.println(x+ ","+ sum);
    }
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Don't tell me you have named your class as `Random`

Comment: Maybe try seeding the random number generator? "new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java -The method sleep(int) is undefined for the type Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591703/java-the-method-sleepint-is-undefined-for-the-type-thread)

Comment: @MartinSchröder, there can be lots of similar question found in StackOverflow ;) :)

Comment: Please show us complete code, including the class declaration and imports.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Yes, show us the first few lines of your .java file.

Answer (score 11):

I'm willing to bet your current class is named `Random`. Is it? Change it or use

```
java.util.Random rnd = new java.util.Random();
```

Otherwise it will try to instantiate your own `Random` class, which obviously doesn't have that method.

Comment: It is java.util.Random actually

Comment: You're missing the point Chiron…

Comment: He's correct though. Added the `java.`, otherwise it wouldn't work.

Comment: I changed the class name, but it still won't work...

Comment: @ArlaudPierre Are you sure that I'm missing the point?

Comment: @user3087534: can you define "it still won't work"? What isn't working? What is the error? How is your file named and how is your class named?

Comment: @Chiron the point is OP called his main class `Random` so Jeroen is suggesting there is a conflict with java.util.Random.

Comment: @ArlaudPierre What does this tell you? rnd.nextInt(29)

Comment: @Chiron nope. Still missing the point. Java thinks rdn is an instance of [DefaultPackage.]Random and not java.util.Random, so nextInt is unknown (because not present in the main class).

Comment: @ArlaudPierre And that is why I said java.util.Random

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I changed it to java.util.Random rnd = new java.util.Random(); and it worked, THANKS!

Comment: @user3087534: glad I could help. Do you understand why this is now working? If you give your own class the same name as a class in the Java libraries, it will usually try to use your class when instantiating an object. That's why you should try to avoid having classes with the same name, or use the full qualifiers (package.subpackage.class) to prevent this ambiguity.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Yeah, I'll be sure to never repeat that in the future, thanks again, you really saved me.